# How do I run a index.jade file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Trying to learn HTML5 and downloaded a test project https://github.com/amiklosi/Comicr. There is a folder named views with a index.jade which I suppose is the start page. What does it take to run that type of files? I can not open it directly in the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jade](http://jade-lang.com/) is a HTML templating engine. All jade files need to be transformed in the HTML.

You need to install to install jade by running

```
npm install jade
```

Also don't forget that you need to install other dependencie like express, nodemailer, etc (see requires in the [source code](https://github.com/amiklosi/Comicr/blob/master/app.js)).

Then run the app using

```
node app.js
```

And the application should by available on http://localhost/3000. All Jade templates will be correctly rendered and displayed as HTML.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is new to me;)

Is there any special requirements for the web hosting to run it? Or can all web hosting run this?

Comment: @Xtreme If you want to deploy the application you need a hosting provider that is supporting node. [Here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) is the list :).

Comment: What is `npm`?  My computer doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food npm is a package manager. Installs, publishes and manages node programs. Install https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 2):

You create a app.js file with the following contents.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('/', function(){
    res.render('index', {option: 'value'});
});
```